# 500 - Internal server error - htdocs: No such file or directory

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, internal-server-error, htdocs

I'm having a problem with installing Wordpress,
I can get to the step where you enter your database details but once I click next it comes up with the error: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

From looking around, it might be the permissions on 'htdocs' but when I try and change the permissions (to 755) it says: 550 Could not change perms on htdocs: No such file or directory

I'm pretty lost at this point, the host is with fasthosts and I can't see any issue on the hosting side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in the htaccess file?

Comment: There isn't a htaccess file there

Comment: WP uses htaccess by default. Anyway, is this shared hosting or not? Do you have access to your server log files? If so you need to have a looksie in them. Try uploading a test.php file with just an echo in it to the root, and go to it in your browser to see if it works

Comment: I have logs but have no idea how what I'm looking at. The hosting is a reseller account.
With Wordpress, the files I unzipped didn't contain a .htaccess file.
What would I put in test.php?

Comment: The test.php was just to see if PHP files work on on the server. If they do, then the server is likely not at fault, and it's the Wordpress files somewhere. If test.php returns the 500 error, then there is likely a server issue - misconfiguration/bad permission/something else. In that case, you need to search the server log. If you don't know what you are looking for in the logs, refresh the web page with the 500 error, then look at the last lines of the log matching the time/date you refreshed the page.

Comment: The wp-admin/install is working, I choose the area, then enter the database details then the 500 error comes up.
I tried installing an earlier Wordpress but it just came up with a 500 or 404 error. Really stumped. I'll take a look at the logs now.

Comment: Sorry I missed that bit in your question :facepalm:. Forget the test.php crap then. Logs should still show something, and is the best way to go since you have access to them.

Comment: Awesome. Now it won't let me download the most recent log file...
550 Can't open u_ex14101813.log: Invalid argument
Error: Critical file transfer error

Comment: *What* gives you that 550? (ftp client?)

Comment: Yeah the FTP client.

Comment: That sounds like a permissions issue. Are you sure you have access to whatever you are doing? Can you log into your hosting control panel and access the logs from there, or SSH perhaps? I'd contact your hosting provider at this point, as it's becoming a completely different question altogether ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set permission all folders on 755.

```
find ./ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Set permission all files on 644.

```
find ./ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Check owner files. and set correction user for owner.
For example in following code, replace `user` with correction owner site.
This code work if you use of `Cpanel`

```
chown user:user /home/user/public_html/ -R
chown user:nobody /home/user/public_html/
```

Comment: This may well be the issue, although currently is a guess. Reviewing logs should show the issue and allow for an *appropriate fix*, rather than changing all folder permissions as a *test fix*.